# vb sql query on field of different types

Tags: mysql, vb.net, excel, vba

I am using SQL command with VB on recordset object.
I am retrieving data from a table in excel, my column of data(param) contains 2 types of data either numbers or characters.
When I run the query I get a type mismatch error.
the query is for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE param=3 OR param=F
```

I also tried

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE param=3 OR param='F'
```

with quotes and same miss match error

When I try:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE param=3
```

the query returns data correctly.

any idea what I need to do?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There may be another solution to this problem, but you can use this approach as well

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE CAST(param AS VARCHAR(30)) = '3' OR CAST(param AS VARCHAR(30)) = 'F'
```

Comment: thank you for this quick answer.  But I am having a new error message: Method 'Open' of object _recordset' failed. Here is my request: SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE T2.`Répondu le` IS NULL AND (CAST(T2.`Typ# Mod#` AS VARCHAR(30)) = '3'  OR CAST(T2.`Typ# Mod#` AS VARCHAR(30)) = 'F')

Comment: Yes. there was an parenthesis error near cast. I fixed it

Comment: yes it is a column and there are back quotes, used, the # is replacing dot (.)

Comment: method Open is failing. SELECT * FROM [sheet1$] as T2 WHERE T2.`Répondu le` IS NULL AND (CAST(T2.`Typ# Mod#` AS VARCHAR(30) )= '3'  OR CAST(T2.`Typ# Mod#` AS VARCHAR(30)) = 'F')

Comment: Not sure but it is your code level error. if possible update your quetion with some more details

Comment: "SELECT * from [Active_CD_PDX_ECM_Users$] AS T2 WHERE T2.`Répondu le` IS NULL AND (CAST(T2.`Typ# Mod#` AS VARCHAR(30) )= '3'  OR CAST(T2.`Typ# Mod#` AS VARCHAR(30)) = 'F') "     It generate a runtime error - Method 'Open' Of Object _Recordset failed

Comment: It wont helpful until and unless you update your question with more detail

Comment: with My_sql_cmd_string(index) ="SELECT * FROM [sheet1$] as T2 WHERE T2.Répondu le IS NULL AND (CAST(T2.Typ# Mod# AS VARCHAR(30) )= '3' OR CAST(T2.Typ# Mod# AS VARCHAR(30)) = 'F') "

Comment: What do you mean with more details? what other details would you like to get?   the code level::: objRecordset_tab(index).Open My_sql_cmd_string(index), _
                ObjConnection_tab(index), adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText